# ASP conditional error

Tags: asp-classic

i am trying to use an ASP conditional here:

```
if (Request.Cookies("username")) and
(Request.Cookies("password")) <> ""
Then
```

And i keep getting this error:

> Type mismatch: '[string: ""]'

Any ideas what I am getting that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
if (Request.Cookies("username") <> "") and (Request.Cookies("password") <> "") Then
```

Answer (score -2):

Actually, I would do the following..

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Cookies("username")) &&
    !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Cookies("password")))
{
    // Do your stuff, here :)
}
```

Get into the habit of using `string.IsNullOrEmpty` for testing variables and `string.Empty` for setting values, if u don't want a string to be `null`.

Comment: Hey! Thanks, how is this different from using == ""

Just want to understand it since im new to ASP

Comment: Assuming the OP means classic ASP then your code isn't in the right language...

IsNullOrEmpty sounds like a handy function to have though.  I just use "if lenb(x)=0" as that serves the same purpose.